# Extra HTML tags appears after translation

Tags: php, google-translate

I'm getting extra html tags after a translation with PHP Google Client library for a specific sentence.

Here the sentence I want to translate :

`<p>Envoie un <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>trait de givre</strong></span> sur l'ennemi infligeant des dégâts de froid et déclenchant l'effet "Ralenti" de la mort </p>`

I obtain this :

`<p> Sends a <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>frost line</strong></span> at the enemy that <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>deals</strong></span> cold damage and unleashes the "Slow motion" effect of death </p>`

As you notice, there is an extra span/strong arround the word "deals" ("infligeant" in French).

If I replace, for instance, "trait de givre" by "sort" (spell), as this :

`<p>Envoie un <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>sort</strong></span> sur l'ennemi infligeant des dégâts de froid et déclenchant l'effet "Ralenti" de la mort</p>`

I obtain the right translation (without any extra html tags):

`<p> Sends a <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>spell</strong></span> on the enemy that deals cold damage and unleashes the "Slow motion" effect of death </p>`

It appears it looks like a cache problem, but I can't identify where and how to clear it on Google Translate API.

```php
$string = '<p>Envoie un <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>trait de givre</strong></span> sur l\'ennemi infligeant des dégâts de froid et déclenchant l\'effet "Ralenti" de la mort</p>';
$client = new TranslateClient(['keyFilePath' => config('translate.GoogleAccounts.en_us')]);
$translation = $client->translate($string, [
    'source' => 'fr',
    'target' => 'en',
    'format' => 'html',
]);
print_r($translation);
```

Give :

```
Array
(
    [source] => fr
    [input] => <p>Envoie un <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>trait de givre</strong></span> sur l'ennemi infligeant des dégâts de froid et déclenchant l'effet "Ralenti" de la mort</p>
    [text] => <p> Sends a <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>frost line</strong></span> at the enemy that <span style="color:#459fe5;"><strong>deals</strong></span> cold damage and unleashes the &quot;Slow motion&quot; effect of death </p>
    [model] => 
)
```